# Friends of Friends on Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

How would one go about structuring a firebase data tree and querying a friends of friends list similar to how facebook is able to recommend friends of friends. I understand that they use a graph database to do this but would this be possible or efficient to do in Firebase. For instance while it is possible to perform such a query in SQL doing a Join it is not necessary the most efficient.
Is it possible and it be done in an efficient and cost effective way?

Below is our current data model we would like to be able to present to users potential people to follow that they are not currently following that the people they follow are currently following.

```
Following
    -userID1
       -followID1:true
       -followID2:true
           .
           .
           .
    -userID2
        -followID1:true
        -followID2:true
          .
          .
          .
```

I would like to query the followers of followers so I could suggest people that current users may wish to follow who they arent already following what kind of query should I perform? What would this look like?

**Below is my current implementation**:

```
exports.getRandomUsers = functions.https.onCall(async (data,context) => {
   const userID = data.userID;

    var currentFollowing = []
    await admin.database().ref(`Following/${userID}/tagsUsers`).orderByChild("isUser").equalTo(true).once("value").then((snapshot) => {

        if(snapshot.exists() === false){
            console.log("empty snapshot: " + snapshot.ref);
            return snapshot.ref;
        }

        snapshot.forEach((node) => {
            currentFollowing.push(node.key)
        })
        return currentFollowing;
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("error getting following: " + error);
        return error;
    })

    console.log("current following.count: " + currentFollowing.length);

    var followersOfFollowersPromises =  currentFollowing.map((followID) => {
        return admin.database().ref(`Following/${followID}/tagsUsers`).orderByChild("isUser").equalTo(true).once("value")
    })

    console.log("followersOfFollowersPromises: " + followersOfFollowersPromises.length);

    var followersOfFollowers = [];//new Set();

    await Promise.all(followersOfFollowersPromises).then((results) => {

        var res = results.filter((result) => {
            console.log("result.exists(): " + result.exists())
            return result.exists();
        })

        res.forEach((result) => {
            console.log("\n\n\n")
            console.log("result: " + JSON.stringify(Object.keys(result.val())));
            const keys = Object.keys(result.val())
            console.log("keys: " + JSON.stringify(keys));
            keys.forEach((key) => {
                console.log("key: " + key);
                if(followersOfFollowers.includes(key) === false){
                    followersOfFollowers.push(key);
                }
            });
                // followersOfFollowers.add(key)});
            // followersOfFollowers = followersOfFollowers.concat(Object.keys(result.val()));
            console.log("\n\n\n")
        })
        // console.log("followers of followers: " + JSON.stringify(followersOfFollowers))
        return 1;
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("error getting followers of followers promises: " + error);
        return error;
    })

    var suggestedFollowers = [];
    while(suggestedFollowers.length < 8){
        suggestedFollowers = suggestedFollowers.concat(followersOfFollowers.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * followersOfFollowers.length),1))
    }
    return suggestedFollowers;

})
```

Comment: This is an incredibly broad topic, and not something that can reasonably be answered in a single Stack Overflow post. It also depends on your exact use-cases, and "similar to facebook" is unfortunately not good enough to answer. To learn more about NoSQL data modeling, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/), and then watch this great video series: [Get to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you for your prompt response and the resouces you provided. Please see above the edits I made showing our specific use case. How would you recomend we query following of following to recommend given our current data structure?

Comment: Are you asking how to get a list of your followers, followers that are not following you? If so, you would generate a list of your followers, followers then query those that are not following you (where your uid is nil in their list, depending on your structure)

Comment: @Jay that sounds like a good approach but my concern is that isn't it possible that this could result in as many queries being run as there are followers of followers for a user?

Comment: It really depends on your structure. Many times with Firebase, the structure is directly driven by what kind of queries you want to run and you may find that denormalizing your data reduces the number of queries needed.

Comment: @Jay Please see my implementation above based on your suggestions is this the correct approach

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the followers of followers, you will quite literally need to do exactly that. First read the first-level followers of the current user, then loop through those, and read the next-level followers of each. Then you deduplicate the results, and finally display them to the user.

In pseudo-code:

```
let ref = firebase.database.ref("Following")
ref.child(auth.currentUser.uid).once("value").then((snapshot) => {
  let suggested = {};
  snapshot.forEach((level1UserSnapshot) => {
    ref.child(level1UserSnapshot.key).once("value").then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((level2UserSnapshot) => {
        suggested[level2UserSnapshot.key] = true;
      });
    });
  });
}
```

You'll want to use promises or `async`/`await` in here to ensure everything is done before you start using the `suggested` results.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write such a detailed answer. My concern is could this potentially reach scalability issues. For instance if a user has 100 followers the first query would return 100 users. Then I would have to run 100 queries for each of those users followers. Let's assume those users each also have 100 followers this could be an array of size 100^100 to parse through.

Comment: @TheRedCamaro3.03.0 It would not be an array to parse. You would first load your follower's uid's, say 100, then iterate over those with a query. The results of *that* would be some uid's which could be loaded into an array. So technically, if you have 100 followers and every one of their followers does not follow you, it would be a 'long list'. However, it's just a a bunch of UID strings so thousands of results is still a tiny amount of data. If that's a significant impact then when you get the results of each query, dump the data back to firebase to release the memory and run your next query